# Receiving a delayed standard output message

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read the standard output of the following [devcon.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311272) command in my application:

```
devcon rescan
```

If I run it in cmd I get the following two lines:

```
Scanning for new hardware.
Scanning completed.
```

**The first line is printed instantly, while the second one is printed with a small delay (which is almost certainly the cause of the problem).**

I want to get this output in my application. I have the following method which should do just that, but instead only prints, as the received output, the first line (the output is stored in the 'message' variable). The [return code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544766(v=vs.85).aspx) of the command I get is 2, which means it fails to execute correctly:

```
public Boolean rescanProgrammer()
    {
        Boolean rescanCompleted = false;
        String path_to_devcon = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() + "\\devcon.exe";
        Boolean oneResultFound = false;

        if (File.Exists(path_to_devcon))
        {
            Process externalApp = new Process();
            externalApp.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // run as admin (only for vista and up)
            externalApp.StartInfo.FileName = path_to_devcon;
            externalApp.StartInfo.Arguments = "rescan"; 
            externalApp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            externalApp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            externalApp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            externalApp.Start();

            List<String> message = new List<String>();

            using (StreamReader reader = externalApp.StandardOutput)
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadLine();
                    message.Add(result);
                    // Check for the line : "1 matching device(s) found."
                    // Usually it's the last line in the output

                    if (result.Contains("Scanning completed."))
                    {
                        oneResultFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            externalApp.WaitForExit();
            // Returned Devcon.exe exit code
            /*
             Return code    Meaning
                0           Success
                1           Requires reboot
                2           Failure
                3           Syntax error
            */
            MessageBox.Show(externalApp.ExitCode + "");

            // Message
            MessageBox.Show(String.Join("\n", message.ToArray()));

            //Check if the line was found
            if (oneResultFound == true)
            {
                // We found the above line and the process exited, so we can
                // safely return a value
                rescanCompleted = true;
                MessageBox.Show("\"Rescan completed\" line found!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Rescan operation didn't complete successfully!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't find Devcon.exe");
        }
        return rescanCompleted;
    }
```

Does somebody know, what do I have to change in order to get the full output?

I've also tried using the `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()`, which also didn't work:

```
using (StreamReader reader = externalApp.StandardOutput)
{
    String temp = reader.ReadToEnd();
    MessageBox.Show(temp);
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how this could be solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the output delayed or incomplete? You are saying both which can't be true.

Comment: When I run the command in cmd, the second line is printed with a small delay. When I run it my application, the second line is not in the received output string.

Comment: Did the tool fail when running it in cmd? Asking because it did fail when you ran it from .NET.

Comment: If I run it as Admin in CMD, it runs ok. if not admin, it fails. But I also put the `externalApp.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";` line in the program, which should run the process with admin rights.

Comment: You will never get to the ReadToEnd() until the stream is closed which occurs when the program terminates.  In stead you must read synchronously and read the available data.  You will get partial data so you need to append each new receive message to end of previous.  You also want to parse around the end of line character(s).